# Turns address into latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: visualforce, javascript, api, google-map

How to retrieve or get the lat/lon by providing the address?, I'm using Google places auto-complete API and you typed the address in the auto-complete text-box and you select the address and the marker pops-up in the google map.

I'm after how to get the lat/lon once the address is pops-up in the map?

I could have done using the [server side apex](http://www.vandeveldejan.com/trigger-geolocation-account-google-map-nearby-accounts/) but it has limitation which is Google limit number of API calls etc...

But how I can do that using `Google Maps Javascript API`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google map `Autocomplete` itself returns the geolocation of the selected place. You can get the latitude and longitude with the following lines of code. Hope this helps.

```
var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
var long = place.geometry.location.lng();
```